# Keep page numbering fixed when shuffling pages for impositioning - InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, booklet, imposition

I am trying to imposition an InDesign booklet myself because I have to export as a PDF. I am going to print from a printer that doesn't have InDesign.

I made a copy of the document and then I am planning to shuffle the pages around into the correct impositioned order. I am wondering if there is a way to keep the page numbers unchanging while you shuffle around? Because when I move the pages InDesign updates the numbers.

Comment: Why do you want to do the impositioning manually, rather than letting InDesign do it for you? The Print Booklet function does exactly this, and you can Print Booklet to a PDF file as well…

Comment: ... and *if* you need to impositioning manually place your InDesign document or exported PDF in *another* InDesign document to avoid altering the original file.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Seems more like answers to me than comments :) Anyone want my upvote?

Comment: @Wolff Seems more like answers to me than comments :) Anyone want my upvote?

Comment: Hi @Wolff I have made a duplicate copy of my document to play around with. I just thought it would be less confusing to have the numbers fixed plus once I shuffle that will affect the current page numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open a *new* InDesign document the same size as your original InDesign document.
- Use `File > Place` to **place individual pages** from 
  the *original* InDesign file into your *new* file.
- Impose pages in the new file however you need.

Page number in the original will not change.

Retain both files.

If you need to edit the original do so in the original file. When you open the imposed file after editing the original, merely update the links.

Comment: Posted before I read comments.. but yeah.. great minds and all that `:)`